# Can you generate a tuple of an object's property types?

Tags: typescript, tuples

Given a type like:

```
type A = {a:string, b:string};
```

I'd like to generate a tuple with all of A's properties. I.e. something like this (the syntax isn't important - only that the proper type is generated):

```
type AProps = PropsToTuple<A>; // -> ["a", "b"]
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: A tuple implies an order. Properties on an object type don't have any particular order. How would TypeScript know property should go first in `AProps`? AFAIK, a _union to tuple_ transformation is not possible with TypeScript. See this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468375328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tuple implies an order. Properties on an object type don't have any particular order. How would TypeScript know property should go first in `AProps`?

If you want a tuple, you need to tell TypeScript what the desired order is.

```
type A = { a: string, b: string };

export const enumerate = <T>() =>
  <U extends T[]>(...elements: WhenIncludesEvery<T, U>): U => elements;

type IncludesEvery<T, U extends T[]> =
  T extends U[keyof U]
    ? true
    : false;

type WhenIncludesEvery<T, U extends T[]> =
  IncludesEvery<T, U> extends true
    ? U
    : never;

const tuple = enumerate<keyof A>()('a', 'b'); // ["a", "b"] 

type AProps = typeof tuple;
```

This solution requires a function to be called in runtime, and is more complex, but it makes sure every property is a) listed b) listed only once.